# Shared Drive / Folder

Tags: nfs, shared-folders, sshfs

I have a Ubuntu server at home with a static up and domains pointed to it.

I would like to allocate a folder to be used on the Home network as a shared folder where anyone on the network can read write and execute.

I have experience with SSHFS and a little bit with NFS and I’ve been trying to find information about how to do this but I haven’t found anything useful. Most of the systems that will be accessing the drive are windows. However I have some Linux machines that will be as well. So I assume I need fat32 formatting with the vfat filesystem.

My question mainly is what kind of software do I need to do this? I would like for it to show up under network places automatically.

Thank you in advance  for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `samba` `apt install samba samba-common-bin` it is so simple to do too, edit one file, set password, restart daemon and your done. Then `nano /etc/samba/smb.conf` in the `[homes]` section change the `yes` to `no` like below to have the share read/writable, at the bottom of the file add your share. Then set the password for the `user_name` you want to be able to access the share with `smbpasswd -a user_name` and restart `samba` `service smbd restart`. All commands run with `sudo` in front of them in the `Terminal` application.

```
# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
read only = no
snip ....
[share-name]
path = /home/user_name/share_directory
writeable=Yes
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
public=no
```

The formatting can be any file system you want, your machine takes care of the reading/writing to it, `samba` takes care of the sharing.

Comment: That’s awesome I’ve heard of samba but only in passing and never directed to me. Can’t believe it’s what I’ve been searching for! Thank you so much!

Comment: Love the name btw, one of my favorite wallpapers is tux with the windows juice box!

Comment: You are welcome nice to read it worked. It was my main machine name for years, I went with a seven dwarfs theme for all my machines, HappyTux, BashfulTux, DopeyTux ... I use it as my user name on linux sites for at least 18 years according to my linux questions registration date of 2003.

Comment: Nice! I went with a space theme, earth for my home machine, moon for a second smaller home machine, Pluto for a pi home machine then I continued by size for non home machines.